# jquery change text onclick problem

Tags: jquery

I have a number of brands that I display, but I want to display only first 5 and have see more brands text. I have everything set up correctly and functionality is fine, but after the click I would like to change the text from see more brands to see less brands.

```
<li style="font-size:12px; margin-left:2px;" class="showmorebrands">
<a onclick="$('#morebrands').toggle('fast', function() {  });">Show More Brands</a></li>
```

I tried inner text, but that changes the text and the html, so my button doesn't work anymore.

I appreciate all help.

Thank you.

EDIT:

The morebrands has inline style display:none;

Comment: Where is the element with the id `morebrands`?

Comment: Those are the brands that are hidden. Should I change it to $(".showmorebrands")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $("li.showmorebrands a").click(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      $('#morebrands').toggle('fast', function() { 
         if($('#morebrands').is(":visible")){
            $this.html("Show More Brands");
         }
         else{
            $this.html("Show Less Brands");
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
<li style="font-size:12px; margin-left:2px;" class="showmorebrands">
    <a>Show More Brands</a>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var $moreBrands = $('#moreBrands'),
        $showHideBrands = $('.showmorebrands a');

    $showHideBrands.click(function(event) {
      $moreBrands.toggle(
        'fast', 
        function() {
          $showHideBrands.text(
            $moreBrands.is(':visible') ? 'Show Less Brands' : 'Show More Brands');
        }
      );
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You are fast, I was writing it up. This is the correct way to do it. Separate presentation from functionality.

Comment: hmm, it works nicely, but when I click on it after it changed to "show less brands" it doesn't change back to show more brands

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Try adding a `preventDefault()`.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: You messed it up. This is not the correct [`$.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) syntax.

Comment: Whoops. I confused myself looking at the other toggle method. I rolled it back.

Comment: I fixed the bug, so the text changes back to "Show More Brands" now. Better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#morebrands').toggle('fast', function() { $(this).text('Show less brands') });
```

Comment: This is wrong. In the toggle callback method `this` will point to `#morebrands` and not the anchor.

Comment: that changes every single hidden brand to "Show less brands"

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Thank you, but that's not necessary. Your answer is way better, and mine really deserves the zero or less than zero score!